# Are links like /rooms/6-30/One-Bedroom-Suite bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, links, ranking

So I am trying to optimize a hotel website for SEO, and I have a question regarding the room links.

I want to put the room title in the link, and I was going to do something like "/rooms/5-One-Bedroom-Suite", however this causes issues because sometimes I have links like "/rooms/6-30-One-Bedroom-Suite" and I want to keep the dash in 6-30.

I tried diving into Regex hell, but that is too painful on the head. Is it necessarily bad practice to do it like this? /rooms/6-30/One-Bedroom-Suite, /rooms/5/One-Bedroom-Suite?

I feel this will make it easier on my head, but I'm afraid google might think it makes no sense and derank the site.

I tried regex for the first solution, but it was too difficult for me to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, URLs like "/rooms/6-30/One-Bedroom-Suite" are generally fine for SEO, provided they are readable, relevant, and consistent across your site.